# A question about the commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator

I'm self-studying quantum mechanics and have a question regarding the commutator.

Since the commutator of two operators is defined as

$[A,B]$ = $AB$ - $BA$

Assuming that these operators do not commute, does that mean that the value of, say $AB$ = (commutator) $+BA$

For example, the commutator between position $x$ and momentum $p$ is
$[x,p] = xp-px$ = $i\hbar$

Does it follow that $xp = i\hbar + px$

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Just to be careful, note that these are operators: $\hat x \hat p = i\hbar \mathbf 1 + \hat p \hat x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Just as $x=y-z$ implies that $y=x+z,$ the identity $[A,B]=AB-BA$ implies $AB=[A,B]+BA.$

Comment: Thank you. 

I know it's an elementary arithmetic operation but I wasn't sure if this was still true with operators.

Comment: @Steven. Yes, it's easy to get confused and uncertain about new things even if they are quite trivial.

Comment: @Steven. It's actually quite common to use $AB = [A,B] + BA,$ e.g. like
$$ A^2 B = A(AB) = A([A,B]+BA) = A [A,B] + ABA = A [A,B] + (AB) A \\ = A[A,B] + ([A,B]+BA)A = A [A,B] + [A,B] A + BA^2$$
which shows that
$$[A^2,B] = A[A,B]+[A,B]A.$$

Comment: @Steven There's no need to be so careful. Almost everything you know about arithmetic still works. The only change is that you can't swap the order anymore, $AB \neq BA$.